# How do I print out each individual item in a list with a formatted string

Tags: c#, string, loops, format, console-application

I know how to print out each individual item of a list using a foreach loop. However in my code it is only printing out the 1st value each time rather than the next value in the list.

Usually you create a list then iterate through each value in the list and print it out individually.

I don't know if it is because I have a method that calculates a value for each item in the list that I am trying to output and it stops at the first value?

Here is my code:

Payment class and properties

```
 public class Payment
    {
        // total amount in GBP earned by the employee during an unspecified period (can be monthly salary, quarterly bonus, weekly laundry benefit etc.)
        public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

        // number of days employee was working from the UK during the period the payment is for
        public int UkWorkdayCount { get; set; }

        // number of days employee was working from a country other than the UK during period the payment is for
        public int ForeignWorkdayCount { get; set; }
    }
```

Calculation method

```
public static decimal CalculateUkTaxableAmount(List<Payment> payments)
    {
        decimal totalTaxableAmount = 0;

        foreach (Payment payment in payments)
        {
            
                var totalAmount = payment.TotalAmount;
                var ukWorkdayCount = payment.UkWorkdayCount;
                var foreignWorkdayCount = payment.ForeignWorkdayCount;

                //Convert workday count to decimal type for calculations
                decimal ukWorkdayDecimal = ukWorkdayCount;
                decimal foreignWorkdayDecimal = foreignWorkdayCount;

                totalTaxableAmount = totalAmount * (ukWorkdayDecimal / (ukWorkdayDecimal + foreignWorkdayDecimal));

                return totalTaxableAmount;  
        }

        return totalTaxableAmount;
    }
```

Main method

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var payments = new List<Payment>
        {
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 3000m, UkWorkdayCount = 15, ForeignWorkdayCount = 5 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 1281.50m, UkWorkdayCount = 3, ForeignWorkdayCount = 18 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 183.07 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 250m, UkWorkdayCount = 31, ForeignWorkdayCount = 0 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 250.00 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 50.63m, UkWorkdayCount = 0, ForeignWorkdayCount = 4 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 0.00 GBP

        };

        //Validation for each payment
        foreach(var p in payments)
        {
            Validate(p);
        }

        var totalTaxableAmount = CalculateUkTaxableAmount(payments);

        //Write each individual item in the list to the console
        payments.ForEach(payments =>
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total UK taxable amount is: {0} GBP",
            totalTaxableAmount.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))));


    }
```

This is the method I used to write each item into the console

```
payments.ForEach(payments =>
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total UK taxable amount is: {0} GBP",
            totalTaxableAmount.ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))));
```

To check each list item was correct I ran the folllowing to print out each value and it works as expected printing each value in the list

```
foreach (Payment p in payments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.TotalAmount);
        }
```

The expected outcome is:

- Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
- Total UK taxable amount is: 183.07 GBP
- Total UK taxable amount is: 250.00 GBP
- Total UK taxable amount is: 0.00 GBP

But I am getting:

- Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
- Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
- Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
- Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP

I also created a new list to add each value after the CalculateUkTaxableAmount() method and iterated through that, but again the output was the same as above

Comment: What's does `Validate(p);` do?

Comment: Sorry I left out the validation method as it is irrelevant to the problem, its just a validation exception that checks the values being passed into the list

Comment: you have `return totalTaxableAmount` in your `foreach` loop, so the method exits after the first iteration

Comment: If I don't have a `return totalTaxableAmount` in the loop for the `CalculateUkTaxableAmount()` method it will just return zero and not the calculated value?

Comment: then change the logic to keep adding to taxable amount instead of re-assigning it each time. as it stands, if you remove the `return`, taxable amount will only be the value calcualted on the last payment. In other words, change `totalTaxableAmount = ` to `totalTaxableAmount +=`. This is assuming you want to return the total taxable amount for all the payments. If that's not what you want, then change the logic to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the entire `List<Payment>` to your calculate method, you should pass each individual `Payment` and get the value from there. You can refer to a working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0S7iHz)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var payments = new List<Payment>
        {
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 3000m, UkWorkdayCount = 15, ForeignWorkdayCount = 5 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 1281.50m, UkWorkdayCount = 3, ForeignWorkdayCount = 18 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 183.07 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 250m, UkWorkdayCount = 31, ForeignWorkdayCount = 0 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 250.00 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 50.63m, UkWorkdayCount = 0, ForeignWorkdayCount = 4 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 0.00 GBP

        };

        //Validation for each payment
        foreach(var p in payments)
        {
            Validate(p);
        }

        //Write each individual item in the list to the console
        payments.ForEach(payment =>
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total UK taxable amount is: {0} GBP",
            CalculateUkTaxableAmount(payments).ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))));
    }
    
    public static decimal CalculateUkTaxableAmount(Payment payment)
    {
        decimal totalTaxableAmount = 0;    
        var totalAmount = payment.TotalAmount;
        var ukWorkdayCount = payment.UkWorkdayCount;
        var foreignWorkdayCount = payment.ForeignWorkdayCount;

        //Convert workday count to decimal type for calculations
        decimal ukWorkdayDecimal = ukWorkdayCount;
        decimal foreignWorkdayDecimal = foreignWorkdayCount;  
        totalTaxableAmount = totalAmount * (ukWorkdayDecimal / (ukWorkdayDecimal + foreignWorkdayDecimal));

        return totalTaxableAmount; 

    }
}

 public class Payment
 {
     // total amount in GBP earned by the employee during an unspecified period (can be monthly salary, quarterly bonus, weekly laundry benefit etc.)
     public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

     // number of days employee was working from the UK during the period the payment is for
     public int UkWorkdayCount { get; set; }

     // number of days employee was working from a country other than the UK during period the payment is for
     public int ForeignWorkdayCount { get; set; }
 }
```

Output:

```
Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
Total UK taxable amount is: 183.07 GBP
Total UK taxable amount is: 250.00 GBP
Total UK taxable amount is: 0.00 GBP
```

Alternate implementation using `List<decimal>` as return type from `CalculateUkTaxableAmount` method [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Zxatq) that yields the same output:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var payments = new List<Payment>
        {
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 3000m, UkWorkdayCount = 15, ForeignWorkdayCount = 5 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 1281.50m, UkWorkdayCount = 3, ForeignWorkdayCount = 18 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 183.07 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 250m, UkWorkdayCount = 31, ForeignWorkdayCount = 0 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 250.00 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 50.63m, UkWorkdayCount = 0, ForeignWorkdayCount = 4 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 0.00 GBP

        };

        //Validation for each payment
        foreach(var p in payments)
        {
           Validate(p);
        }
        
        var totalTaxableAmount = CalculateUkTaxableAmount(payments);
        //Write each individual item in the list to the console
        int i=0;
        payments.ForEach(payment =>
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total UK taxable amount is: {0} GBP",
            totalTaxableAmount[i].ToString("F", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),i++)));
    }
    
public static List<decimal> CalculateUkTaxableAmount(List<Payment> payments)
    {
        List<decimal> totalTaxableAmount = new List<decimal>();
    
        foreach (Payment payment in payments)
        {
            
                var totalAmount = payment.TotalAmount;
                var ukWorkdayCount = payment.UkWorkdayCount;
                var foreignWorkdayCount = payment.ForeignWorkdayCount;

                //Convert workday count to decimal type for calculations
                decimal ukWorkdayDecimal = ukWorkdayCount;
                decimal foreignWorkdayDecimal = foreignWorkdayCount;

                totalTaxableAmount.Add(totalAmount * (ukWorkdayDecimal / (ukWorkdayDecimal + foreignWorkdayDecimal))); 
        }

        return totalTaxableAmount;
    }
}

 public class Payment
 {
     // total amount in GBP earned by the employee during an unspecified period (can be monthly salary, quarterly bonus, weekly laundry benefit etc.)
     public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

     // number of days employee was working from the UK during the period the payment is for
     public int UkWorkdayCount { get; set; }

     // number of days employee was working from a country other than the UK during period the payment is for
     public int ForeignWorkdayCount { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: I see what you did, is there no way to achieve this without passing the `CalculateUkTaxableAmount()` method into the ForEach loop itself. It just seems to make that method overly complicated rather than separating, I feel like it violating a SOLID principle

Comment: @JaredMackay And what do you expect to get from the `CalculateUkTaxableAmount` ? It cannot be a decimal in this case but has to be `List<decimal>`. If you want to change the return type of this method then we can do something about this.

Comment: @JaredMackay Check out this implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Zxatq

Comment: @RufusL Ahh well indeed it is. But on the online .NET fiddle, it is not showing any errors. Not sure what could be the cause of that

Comment: @RahulSharma I stand corrected! Maybe because I'm on a really old compiler (4.6.2)

Comment: @RufusL Even on the .NET fiddle, when you change the compiler version to .NET 4.7.2, then the error pops up so your point is also valid. Not sure what they have changed internally to handle this

Answer (score 1):

Since `TaxableAmount` is a calculated field based solely on properties of the class, you could just add it as a read-only property in the class itself:

```
public class Payment
{
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public int UkWorkdayCount { get; set; }
    public int ForeignWorkdayCount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalTaxableAmount
    {
        get
        {
            decimal totalWorkdays = UkWorkdayCount + ForeignWorkdayCount;
            // Avoid division by zero error by returning 0 if totalWorkdays is 0
            return totalWorkdays == 0 
                ? 0 
                : TotalAmount * (UkWorkdayCount / totalWorkdays);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your code to print out the amounts might look something like this (note that I changed the format to currency and am using GB culture):

```
payments.ForEach(payment => 
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total UK taxable amount is: {0} GBP", 
        payment.TotalTaxableAmount.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB")))));
```

Output:

```
Total UK taxable amount is: £2,250.00 GBP
Total UK taxable amount is: £183.07 GBP
Total UK taxable amount is: £250.00 GBP
Total UK taxable amount is: £0.00 GBP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like That:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var payments = new List<Payment>
        {
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 3000m, UkWorkdayCount = 15, ForeignWorkdayCount = 5 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 2250.00 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 1281.50m, UkWorkdayCount = 3, ForeignWorkdayCount = 18 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 183.07 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 250m, UkWorkdayCount = 31, ForeignWorkdayCount = 0 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 250.00 GBP
            new Payment { TotalAmount = 50.63m, UkWorkdayCount = 0, ForeignWorkdayCount = 4 }, //Total UK taxable amount is: 0.00 GBP

        };

        //Validation for each payment
        foreach(var p in payments)
        {
            Validate(p);
            var totalTaxableAmount = CalculateUkTaxableAmount(payments);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total UK taxable amount is: {0} GBP",totalTaxableAmount.ToString("F",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

        }


    }
    
    public static decimal CalculateUkTaxableAmount(Payment payment)
    {
        decimal totalTaxableAmount = 0;    
        var totalAmount = payment.TotalAmount;
        var ukWorkdayCount = payment.UkWorkdayCount;
        var foreignWorkdayCount = payment.ForeignWorkdayCount;

        //Convert workday count to decimal type for calculations
        decimal ukWorkdayDecimal = ukWorkdayCount;
        decimal foreignWorkdayDecimal = foreignWorkdayCount;  
        totalTaxableAmount = totalAmount * (ukWorkdayDecimal / (ukWorkdayDecimal + foreignWorkdayDecimal));

        return totalTaxableAmount; 

    }
}

 public class Payment
 {
     // total amount in GBP earned by the employee during an unspecified period (can be monthly salary, quarterly bonus, weekly laundry benefit etc.)
     public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

     // number of days employee was working from the UK during the period the payment is for
     public int UkWorkdayCount { get; set; }

     // number of days employee was working from a country other than the UK during period the payment is for
     public int ForeignWorkdayCount { get; set; }
 }
```